# Instagram API - get posts from single user

Tags: php, jquery, json, instagram, instagram-api

I am really struggling to work with the Instagram API. I currently have this code in a file called `data.php` which I want to return a JSON response which I can process in a JS file but I am getting this response `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Here is the code:

```
<?php

$access_token = '********';
$client_id = '********';
$client_secret = "*******";
$user = "*******";

$endpoint = '/media/657988443280050001_25025320';
$params = array(
  'access_token' => '********',
  'count' => 10,
);

$signature = generate_sig($endpoint, $params, $client_secret);

var_dump("Signature: ". $signature);

$data = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/$user/media/recent/?access_token=$signature");

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
echo $data;

function generate_sig($endpoint, $params, $secret) {

  $sig = $endpoint;

  ksort($params);

  foreach ($params as $key => $val) {
    $sig .= "|$key=$val";
  }

  return hash_hmac('sha256', $sig, $secret, false);

}
```

?>

Here are my app settings. It is in `Sandbox Mode` and hasn't been submitted for review.

[image]

Comment: That endpoint looks weird, where did you get it?

Comment: From the docs - Could you provide a better endpoint for a single user's posts? @quelquecosa

Comment: Send me the link from the docs

Comment: @quelquecosa - here in the PHP context - https://www.instagram.com/developer/secure-api-requests/

Comment: are you done with this or need an answer ?